Unify multiple domains/platforms using one MX record
We have two separate domains A and B. We have three platforms Platform A B and C. Since there is a ton of work to migrate everyone to one domain A on platform B and leadership wants everyone to use an email address of domain A I was wondering if we could set up a proxy server where the MX record would point for all email addressed to domain A that could distribute to all three platforms and using aliases deliver to both domain A and B whilst the heavy lift of migration is going on in the background.
Platform A is Google Workspace (where MX record currently points)
Platform B is O365 where domain A and B are migrating to
Platform C is O365 where domain B lives
